# EF Include navigation property with specific Map

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this two classes on EF NET Core which represent database objects:

```
public partial class Clientes
{
    public int IdCliente { get; set; }
    public TiposIva CondicionIva { get; set; }
}

public partial class TiposIva
{
    public int IdCondicionIva { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Letra { get; set; }
    public string Fiscal { get; set; }

    public Enumerador ToEnumerador() {
        return new Enumerador { ID = this.IdCondicionIva, Valor = this.Descripcion };
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a query that return a Clientes object, and include TiposIva property (navigation), but not all of them, Only the ones represented on ToEnumerador Method.

**In fact I need a Clientes Object with a Enumerador Property filled with related TiposIva data**

I try this:

```
return this.RepositoryContext.Clientes
            .Include(c => c.CondicionIva.ToEnumerador())
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

But I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Mensaje = The Include property lambda expression 'c => c.CondicionIva.ToEnumerador()' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
> Origen = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
> Seguimiento de la pila:
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ResultOperators.Internal.IncludeExpressionNode.CreateResultOperator(ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
> at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.ResultOperatorExpressionNodeBase.ApplyNodeSpecificSemantics(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
> at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.MethodCallExpressionNodeBase.Apply(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
> at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.ApplyAllNodes(IExpressionNode node, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
> at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.ApplyAllNodes(IExpressionNode node, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
> at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression query, IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDatabase database, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
> at OhmioRepositorios.ClientesRepository.Cargar(Int32 IdCliente) in C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Fuentes Ohmio WEB\Server EF\OhmioRepositorios\ClientesRepository.cs:line 40
> at OhmioServicios.Servicios.Clientes_svc.Cargar(Int32 id) in C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Fuentes Ohmio WEB\Server EF\OhmioServicios\Servicios\Clientes_svc.cs:line 50
> at OhmioWEBAPINetCore.Controllers.ClientesController.GetCliente(Int32 idCliente) in C:\Users\Eric\Documents\Fuentes Ohmio WEB\Server EF\OhmioWEBAPINetCore\Controllers\ClientesController.cs:line 38
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()

Comment: Is `ToEnumerador()` a method in `TiposIva`? Well, whatever it is, in `Include` you can *only* use navigation properties. If you want to map your entities to something else, use AutoMapper.

Comment: Yes, ToEnumerador is a method of TiposIva. Of course I can manually map the property, or use Automapper, but i'm using this models with repository pattern and my idea is to use navigation properties to create my model.

Comment: `Include` is not equivalent of `Select` / AutoMapper `Map` / `ProjectTo`. It is intended to load the related *entities*, which means objects with *all* their properties. So `Include` / `ThenInclude` accept only property (the exception message is telling you exactly that). For more info, see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) documentation topic.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work that way. 
"Include" you can only use navigation properties. 
You don't need call .ToEnumerador() method inside "Include", use only TiposIva.

Comment: Yes, I know that. If I only use TiposIva it works but I get then whole object. Why I cannot return a new type if I specify how to cast it?

Comment: Using this way the whole object load, if any, because it is made an Inner Join.
You can turn this method into an unmapped property where Get returns the object, have you tried it?